# Grout near shower drain falling out

Tags: grout

I built my house three years ago. The shower has tiled base. Recently the grout surrounding my shower drain has fallen out and it has opened a small crack between shower drain and the tile (images attached). The crack is small 5 cm in length, 0.3 cm wide and 3 cm deep.

Please let me know do I fix it. I have tried filling it with "dunlop ready-to-go grout" twice already. It let it dry for three days but it melted away as soon as I took my first shower.

Kindly guide me how to fix it properly. Really appreciate your help. I would prefer not to hire a titler for such a small job : (

[image: length]
[image: depth]

Thanks
Waseem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the drain grate and put some plumbers putty or masking tape on the bottom of the drain frame and against the tile to prevent the new grout from just falling through the crack. Chip out any other grout that might be loose and clean off any old grout from the frame and tile edge. Then get a small package of epoxy grout and fill in that crack and let it cure according to the instructions. Then remove the putty or tape and reinstall the grate.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this grate could be removed (or at least I don't know how to remove it safely : (  one silly question, that round thingy is the grate ? Or whole square thingy is the grate?

Comment: The round thing is the grate and it should pop out or unscrew, there has to be a way to clean out the drain.